# Is it possible to configure the breakpoints in MudBlazor?

Tags: mudblazor

I'm trying to change the default breakpoint values of MudBlazor.
The [MudBlazor Docs](https://mudblazor.com/features/breakpoints#components) describes these values. For instance, there is the xs value <600px. I would like to change that to <500px.

What I found was the `MudBlazor.Breakpoints` class. This class contains all breakpoints as a property. But I couldn't find out where this class is getting instantiated. The `MudThemeProvider` does not have any breakpoint property. Also, the `MudBreakpointProvider`
doesn't seem to have a hock.